# can I generate an xpath from an element in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

To clarify, I don't mean find_element_by_xpath, I mean this:

```
data = driver.find_element_by_id('table')
rows = data.find_elements_by_tag('tr')

for row in rows:
     ... logic stuff
     cells = row.find_elements_by_tag('td')
     my_saved_cool_xpath = cells[0].get_xpath()

... logic code that changes the dom

specific_cell = driver.find_by_xpath(my_saved_cool_xpath)
```

I need to somehow save specific cells that don't have an id or any identifier really so that after DOM changes I can come back to those specific cells

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative xpath of table if the table may shift somewhere else

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ID1']/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")
```